# Rails, Octopus, access variable in master defined in slave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, scope, octopus

I would like to access the variable defined in the slave1 scope inside of the master scope. How do I scope the variable properly so it is set in the slave block and available in the master block?

```
Octopus.using(:slave1) do
  locations_with_wrong_country_code_ids = Location.where(country: "USA").ids
end

Octopus.using(:master) do
  Location.where(id: locations_with_wrong_country_code_ids).each do |location|
    location.country = "US"
    location.save
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
locations_with_wrong_country_code_ids = Octopus.using(:slave1) do
  Location.where(country: "USA").ids
end

Octopus.using(:master) do
  Location.where(id: locations_with_wrong_country_code_ids).each do |location|
    location.country = "US"
    location.save
  end  
end
```